# Remote debug WP8 Cordova app like Android or iOS?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, remote-debugging

is it possible to remote debug an Cordova application as easy as with android (in chrome) or iOS (in Safari)?

I don't need a C# debugger in visual stuido, but I need a WebView remote debugger. Did not find this option in the Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not as easy as with Android or iOS. However, you can still get remote debugging to work but it is far from ideal. Check out [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/). It allows you to debug your windows phone 8 app by inserting a javascript library in your html pages.